# If the Roman Empire in the Year 90 AD Found a Living Tyrannosaurus Rex, What Creature in Their Mythology Would They Most Likely Mistake It For?

Tags: alternate-history, mythical-creatures, dinosaurs, mythology, prehistoric-times

I'm writing a story where a group of mischievous aliens teleport iconic creatures to inappropriate time periods. (Dimetrodons in colonial Germany, Pterodactyls in the medieval Ottoman Empire, Plesiosaurus in feudal Japan, etc.) In the chapter I am writing, a Roman Cohort discovers a living Tyrannosaurus Rex. They barely manage to capture it while it is sleeping. After some debate, it is decided by the emperor that the beast is to be killed in the colosseum for the entertainment of the Roman people. My problem is when I came to realize that they would not call the creature by the name we have given it. More probably, they would have mistaken it for a creature within their mythology. What beast in Roman/Greek mythology would the Romans most likely mistake a T-Rex for, based on its demeaner, size, and physical appearance?

Comment: "*More probably, they would have mistaken it for a creature within their mythology.*" Personally, I disagree with this unless the resemblance is striking because when something is right in front of you, things are very different. I think this is more a modern day notion of the past, but it's your story.

Comment: For some tips on how the Romans named new animals see Giraffe = cameleopardis = camel-leopard or Ostrich = Struthocamelus = sparrow-camel. They also used Ancient Greek names like Rhinoceros = Nose-horn or Hippopotamus = river-horse.

Comment: Your list of examples forgot [stegosaurus in Cambodia](https://coolinterestingstuff.com/the-unexplainable-mystery-of-the-cambodian-stegosaurus) .

Comment: I am most curious about "colonial germany".

Comment: @Willk By "colonial Germany," I was referring to German East Africa pre-WW1. Sorry if I worded it strangely.

Comment: What research have you done into beasts in Greco-Roman mythology that doesn't cover this? Consider the works of Tom Holt, Tom Sharpe and many another that rely on mythic references. How far might they have got by asking SE?

Comment: FYI, the proper spelling is Tyrannosaurus rex, lowercase rex, and T. rex for short. The genus (Tyrannosaurus) is always capitalised, while the specific epithet (rex) never is. Technically it should also be italicised, but in non-scientific writing that may be more confusing than anything.

Answer (score 24):

**Dragon**

[image]

The word [Dragon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dragons_in_Greek_mythology) comes from Ancient Greek mythology, where it is used to refer to a handful of different large reptiles. Ancient Greek was as much an auxiliary language to Latin, as Latin is to modern English. Roman Nobility typically spoke Greek amongst themselves and were often sent to Greece for part of their education. Latin is a sufficiently vague language that I can imagine the word "draco" being used for a large real reptile.

Probably they'd add an extra word to distinguish it from other named mythological dragons. So **Draco Galliae** (Dragon from Gaul) after the country where they found it, Or **Draco Agrippae** (Agrippa's Dragon) after the General who led the expedition.

For some tips on how the Romans named new animals see Giraffe = cameleopardis = camel-leopard or Ostrich = Struthocamelus = sparrow-camel. They also used Ancient Greek names like Rhinoceros = Nose-horn or Hippopotamus = river-horse. Since the names are so vague to begin with I think **Gallic Lizard** or **Agrippa's Lizard** would work just fine.

Comment: I believe that part of the basis for the myth of dragons is that ancient people heard about the dinosaur fossils lying on the ground in parts of central Asia. So, seeing a live dinosaur would have confirmed that the myth of dragons was real.

Comment: Note that both _cameleopardis_ and _struthocamelus_ are also Ancient Greek, like _rhinoceros_ or _hippopotamus_. Also, why do you say the Roman nobility spoke Greek amongst themselves? Are you perhaps thinking of Byzantine nobility?

Answer (score 14):

### Some manner of bird: Hippalectryon?

[image]
It is a contentious topic, but nowadays [museums portray *Tyrannosaurus* with feathers](https://www.nytimes.com/2019/03/07/arts/design/t-rex-exhibition-american-museum-of-natural-history.html).  The Romans, being the sort of literal-minded people who declared that [all spotted hyenas are male](http://www.bbc.com/earth/story/20141028-the-truth-about-spotted-hyenas) based on observation, would certainly not hesitate to call a feathered animal - *any* feathered animal - a bird.  This is particularly likely to be true if they had the opportunity to see young (the NYT photo linked above is how a 1-year-old is thought to look)

But ... what *kind* of bird?  The Romans probably did not have a strong notion of the half-human tengu to use, while they would have too precise an image for the Bennu.  The Roc, among other things, is too good a flyer.  Depending on the creature's vocalizations, they might call it an Alectryon or a Harpy.

My guess, however, is that they will call it a [Hippalectryon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hippalectryon) (ἱππαλεκτρυών).  This is a terrible stretch from the illustration from Wikipedia below, yes!  But the hippopotamus doesn't really look that much like a river horse, does it?

Besides, every warrior in the audience will have one daydream above all else: not to *slay* the beast, but to build a howdah on its back, and atop that throne, lead an army to ceaseless victory!
[image]

Comment: New skin impressions discovered revealed that T-Rex was actually mostly, if not entirely [covered in a scaly skin](https://www.nationalgeographic.com/animals/article/tyrannosaurus-rex-skin-fossils-feathers-scales-science), a trait that was probably observed in their earlier stages, so it turns out they did look superficially more like giant biped lizards than giant monster birds. I can say however that if it truly was devoid of feathers and appeared in ancient Greece, Diogenes wouldn't stop until he managed to either capture or lure it just so he could show his "man" to Plato.

Comment: This is a valid reference - but note it precedes the 2019 museum exhibition I linked above.  *Patches* of the adult skin are known to be featherless - but if any significant feathers remained, this would not escape the notice of the Romans.  Also, the half-horse nature of the Hippalectryon would help to excuse the bare patches.

Comment: I don't think Tengu, Bennu, or Roc come from Roman Mythology.

Comment: The Bennu is Egyptian, which should be well familiar to Romans.  Almost half their empire was in Africa.  As I said the tengu should be unfamiliar, but it is possible that the Romans had more travellers, books, or legends than we know.

Comment: @MikeSerfas This raises an interesting question about how you translate "Hippalectryon" into English (presumably the story is written in English and not Latin).

Comment: Sorry, I mislinked the article.  It is ἱππα = horse + λεκτρυών = rooster.  (The term may be easier to apply if certain colors are apparent)

Comment: @MikeSerfas Were the Romans familiar with Ancient Egyptian mythology? I know the Sphinx somehow got from Ancient Egypt to Greece to Rome but have never seen references to other creatures. Keep in mind Roman Egypt was not the Ancient Egypt of the Pharoahs.

Comment: @ProjectApex what's your Diogenes' "man" story a reference to?

Comment: @theonlygusti Congratulations, you are one of today's lucky ten thousand! Plato and his Academy once defined man as a "featherless biped". Diogenes the cynic, being Diogenes the cynic, plucked a chicken and held it up to the Academy saying "Behold, a man!" Subsequently, the Academy redefined man as a "featherless biped with broad flat nails".

Comment: @ProjectApex: I had predicted this. A creature of the scale of an adult T-Rex has no want of down feathers.

Comment: @theonlygusti to a tale in which supposedly Plato would've defined a man as a fatherless biped, a description to which Diogenes answered by completely plucking a chicken and bringing it to Plato, resulting in the addition of "with broad flat nails" to said definition.